# How to compare a value from one data frame to the range specified in two columns of another data frame, and return the value of a third column

Tags: r

Consider the following data frames

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjaGL.png)
[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFh5U.png)

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:10,
                  Score = c(73, 53, 8, 100, 39, 62, 78, 89, 61, 18))

df2 <- data.frame(Category = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90),
                  Score_min = c(1, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91),
                  Score_max = c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100))
```

I want to see which df2$Category each df1$Score is by testing the range between columns df2$Score_min and df2$Score_max

Meaning, for each Score in df1, I want to see where it lies in the range between Score_min and Score_max in df2, and return the Category variable in df2

The output i am hoping to obtain is

[final.df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNDQd.png)

```
final.df <- data.frame(ID = 1:10,
                       Score = c(73, 53, 8, 100, 39, 62, 78, 89, 61, 18)) %>% 
  mutate(Category = c(70, 50, 10, 90, 30, 60, 70, 80, 60, 20))
```

I have tried left_join and lapply with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df1 |>
  left_join(df2, join_by(Score >= Score_min, Score <= Score_max))
```